# How to get the MenuItem name when right-clicking any menu item?

Tags: delphi, winapi, menuitem, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit Delphi 11 VCL Application on Windows 10, when RIGHT-CLICKING any menu item, I need to get the name of the clicked MenuItem.

I use a `TApplicationEvents` component and this code to get notified when I click on any menu item:

```
procedure TformMain.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  case Msg.message of
    Winapi.Messages.WM_COMMAND:
      begin
        CodeSite.Send('TformMain.ApplicationEvents1Message: WM_COMMAND');
      end;
  end;
end;
```

However:

1. How to get notified only when RIGHT-clicking the menu item?
2. How to get the NAME of the clicked MenuItem?

Comment: `WM_COMMAND` is issued when a menu item is selected (ie, LEFT-clicked). To allow RIGHT-clicking to select a menu item, `TrackPopupMenu/Ex()` must be called with the `TPM_RIGHTBUTTON` flag (which it is not by default). To detect a RIGHT-click on a menu item, you have to display the menu by calling `TrackPopupMenuEx()` with the `TPM_RECURSE` flag, and then handle the `WM_MENURBUTTONUP` message to the menu's owner window.

Comment: Related/dupe: [Detect left/right mouse button on menu item click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041782/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have several forms in my application and several (popup) menus on each of these forms, a special solution is needed here:

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  case Msg.message of
      Winapi.Messages.WM_COMMAND:
      begin
        // Todo: Check HERE for RightMouseButtonDown - BUT HOW? (Or how to check HERE for modifier keys?)

        var ThisMenuItem := GetMenuItem(Msg.wParam);
        if Assigned(ThisMenuItem) then
        begin
          CodeSite.Send('TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message: Clicked MenuItem Name', ThisMenuItem.Name);
        end;

      end;
  end;
end;

function TForm1.GetMenuItem(const aWParam: NativeUInt): TMenuItem;
var
  ThisMenuItem: TMenuItem;
begin
  Result := nil;
  var ThisForm := Screen.ActiveForm; // works on any form in the application
  for var i := 0 to ThisForm.ComponentCount - 1 do
  begin
    if ThisForm.Components[i] is TMenu then
    begin
      ThisMenuItem := TMenu(ThisForm.Components[i]).FindItem(aWParam, fkCommand);
      if Assigned(ThisMenuItem) then
      begin
        Result := ThisMenuItem;
        EXIT;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes: why using a separate variable if you could use `result` right away (in the function)?

Comment: Programmers often use a separate variable to make the code better understandable for non-programmers.

Comment: No: [The myth of increased readability](https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/why-unnecessary-variables-are-bad-your-code). Writing `if result<> nil then exit;` would be more clear. Even the name `ThisMenuItem` is wrong, because it's not related to any "this", and should be named `FoundItem` at most, if not `Item` right away. Counter question: why didn't you chose `ThisFormMenuItem`?

Comment: Why are you interested in my variable names?

Comment: An earlier version of your answer included "_Any optimizations?_", hence my comments. This answer also only repeats what Uwe Raabe already answered based on your question - your follow-up request is not in the original question, yet you chose your own as "correct". Do not ignore what others contribute, and do not ignore that this is public domain, not "your" code - it is now available to everyone (just like everyone's help was available to you).

Answer (score 2):

Each *TMenu* (i.e. *TMainMenu* or *TPopupMenu*) offers a method *FindItem*, which allows you to find an item by varying criteria. In your case the correct call for the form's main menu would be

```
TheMenuItem := Menu.FindItem(Msg.wParam, fkCommand);
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. But how to get the TMenu (i.e. TMainMenu or TPopupMenu) name?

Comment: @user1580348 Why do you need the name?

Comment: *Menu* is a property of *TForm*.

Comment: @user1580348 The form itself has its properties where a `TMainMenu` or `TPopupMenu` is assigned - just try either one. Otherwise enumerate all Controls.

Comment: It would be useful to detect which menu (TMainMenu or TPopupMenu) is currently opened. Could `EnumThreadWindows` be used to achieve that?